# How to create dataset on mainframe using FTP from java

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe

I am trying to FTP a text file to mainframe using java. I am able to create a member in PDS using below code.

```
//Function to FTP the report
public void sendReport() throws IOException

{
        FTPSClient ftp = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        String protocol="TLS";

        //Connecting to mainframe server for ftp transfer    
        ftp = new FTPSClient(protocol); 
        ftp.connect(hostname);
        ftp.login(user,password);
        ftp.execPBSZ(0);
        ftp.execPROT("P");
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);

        int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        System.out.println("Received Reply from FTP Connection:" + reply);
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) 
            System.out.println("Connected To Mainframe");
        else
            System.out.println("Not connected to Mainframe..Check ID or Password");

        //Setting mainframe PDS for reports
        boolean success = ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("***Mainframe Directory***");
        if (success) 
            System.out.println("Successfully changed PDS.");
        else 
            System.out.println("Failed to change PDS. See Mainframe's reply.");

        //Sending Report to mainframe PDS
        File f1 = new File(dkReportName);
        in = new FileInputStream(f1);
        boolean done = ftp.storeFile("DKI"+dkReportName.substring(14,18), in);
        in.close();
        if (done) 
            System.out.println("FILE FTP SUCCESSFUL"); 
        else 
            System.out.println("FILE FTP NOT SUCCESSFUL");

        ftp.logout();
        ftp.disconnect();
}
```

user,password and hostname variables are being set in appContext.xml.
However, I want to create a PS dataset. 
Could anyone please suggest a way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, this is for the MVS file space and not USS.

When creating a dataset with FTP you need to give the host some information about files size, attributes, etc.

This [page on IBM's website](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1016959) outlines a list of commands that you can execute to setup for the transfer.  The basic sequence would be something like:

`site cyl`
`site pri=5`
`site sec=5`
`site recfm=fb`

and you can combine more than one command on a line:

`site lrecl=80 blksize=3120`

Execute these commands before the transfer and the file should be allocated with your desired characteristics.

Based on your coding example here is a sample that should work:

```
ftp.sendCommand("site",
                "cyl pri=5 sec=5 recfm=fb filetype=seq lrecl=80 blksize=3120");
```